# When order is placed can multiple emails be set as recepients in virtuemart 3?

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I am trying to send order placed mails to merchants different mail ids. Can any one give me the idea/solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While I have been using VM few years ago, I've had the same problem. Clients always wanted at least two email addresses as recepients, and I always needed my admin's email to receive orders for shop monitoring purposes. I have tried many extensions with no satisfaction whatsoever, so one day it occured to me to try with virtual email forwarder instead.

In shop's CPanel I always create virtual email forwarder 'orders@shopdomain.com', and forward it to any number of real email addresses required. I set that email as Main Vendor's address and even use it as shop's main address in Global Config, so that way it receives all system messages.

With this approach and it's combinations, one can have great freedom in configuring messaging subsystem of any shop, regardless of e-commerce extension.

Comment: Hi Mikan, this is a great "out of the box" solution. I haven't tested it in this case but entering multiple emails separated by commas into the recipient email field often works in this situation too.

Comment: @NeilRobertson Thanx mate... :-)  You might be right about multiple emails separated by commas for some other extensions (JComments for one), but I'm not sure about VM. In VM you cannot enter multiple emails into Main Vendors config, at least in last version I have experience with (3.0.6). Thanks for the tip though...

Comment: Hi @Mikan, I am new to VM, Can you tell me how to create virtual email forwarder in VM. Thanks.

Comment: You can't create virtual email forwarder inside the Joomla! You can create virtual email forwarder ONLY in Control Panel of your hosting provider, usualy WHM cPanel. I am afraid that guidelines for a such endeavor are otside the scope of this JSE site. You can always ask Google though, or seek a help from your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

In VirtueMart 3.2.14 or later you can add multiple email addresses to receive the confirmation emails.

Go to
-> VirtueMart Configuration
-> Second Tab, Orders
-> Setting: Additional vendor email addresses.

You can add multiple email addresses separated by a semi colon.
Have a look at the tooltip of the setting.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing. Plesse take our [tour].